# Python Requests Get not Working for "HTTP" request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an issue with using python requests module while trying to get response with http protocol for websites.

Requests works for https sites.

Ideally I am trying to develop a script which would get a http website and check if it is redirecting to https website.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36' }

url = "https://www.google.com"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
```

Whereas using url with "http://www.google.com" fails, it should redirect https://www.google.com which should provide some response code, but it fails.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36' }

url = "http://www.google.com"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
```

Ends up with  below errors with the below errors. Please advise.

> sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001D3A496A9A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Answer (score 1):

The reason you  have these error with your requests could be multiple like a firewall, proxy settings, or ISP restrictions that block connections to non-secure sites, there is different solution, here is one using the `requests` library to redirects and detect if the website is redirecting to the secure version.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "http://www.google.com"

try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, allow_redirects=True)
    print(f"Status Code: {r.status_code}")

    if r.url.startswith("https://"):
        print("The website has redirected to the secure version (https).")
    else:
        print("The website did not redirect to the secure version (https).")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

If that still dont work check your network settings, firewall configurations, or reach out to your ISP.

Comment: Thanks Saxtheowl. It didnt work so tried switching to a less restricted network and it worked. Thanks for highlighting.